# Drawing graph of confidence band in sas

Tags: plot, graph, sas, confidence-interval

Using the simple code below, I made a graph of the cdf.

```
data record;
input v @@;
cards;
16.3 14.2 14.7 16 15.7
;
proc univariate data=record;
cdfplot;
run;
```

Now I want to add some lines to show the confidence band. I tried "proc sgplot" but couldn't find any that worked for this. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Grab the data from PROC UNIVARIATE using an ODS table and the use SGPLOT to graph it. Then you can add your confidence band.

Answer (score 1):

- Get the data from PROC UNIVARIATE
- Graph it using SGPLOT
- Add your bands

```
proc univariate data=record;
cdfplot ;
ods output cdfplot=graphData;
run;

proc sgplot data=graphData;
step x=ecdfx y=ecdfy;
band .....;
run;
```